# Parallelization in Neuro-Fuzzy system

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am working on Meta-Cognitive Neuro-fuzzy system and attempting to port the features extraction process of dataset on GPU and gather it back to give it to CPU...but in this process why the accuracy of the system is reduced?

Comment: Is it possible to post some code of the exchange between the GPU and CPU?

Comment: function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
load('dataset','dataset');
set(handles.lblOutput,'String','Processing...');
pause(0.1);
%train a Meta Cognitive ANFIS Classifier for this data
features = dataset(:,1:end-1);
g1=gpuArray(features);
classes = dataset(:,end);
g2=gpuArray(classes);
e0 = g1(1:round(size(g1,1)/2),:);
eg = g1(round(size(g1,1)/2):size(g1,1),:);
anfis_data = [g1,g2];
f1=gather(g1);
f2=gather(g2);
%Generate a FCM based fis matrix
fismat = genfis3(f1,f2);